# Hyperlink to other tables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

I think you all are familiar with MS Excel's hyperlink feature and how you can create an spreadsheet with links between different sheets so you can move around with ease.
I want the same feature in MS Access, the set up is like this: I have a table for each of my clients, and i have A table that has all clients, and i want to jump between this table and clients' tables with the help of hyperlink. 
But unfortunately in MS Access the hyperlinks can't point to a location inside the database, and the problem with Excel is that it is too slow, and now that my clients has gone over 1k it takes several minutes for it to open.

Any kind of help or advice is appreciated, thank you guys, and have a nice day

Comment: In relational databases you use one single table for the same kind of data, not  multiple ones. So your first challenge would be to design an appropriate database structure.

Comment: You are trying to use Access as if it were a spreadsheet. It is not. You need to read up on relational database design and re-design your tables. Then build forms to do your daily work in, rather than working directly in tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, yes you are right my work is based on previous sloppy designs, and yet i was lazy to start over so i was hoping for quick fix. So i think using forms in MS Access is best answer, right?